# Submitting structured HashMap through POST (without AJAX)

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I'm trying to catch a POJO as a post Page, rather than an ajax call (since I'm returning a file in the end and the request is too complex for a GET call).

Basically the POJO looks something like:

```
@Data public class A { private String a; private String b; private String c; }
@Data public class B { private Integer n; private Map<String, A> m; }
```

The controller expects the B item, so something like:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping("/url") public HttpEntity<byte[]> getFile(@RequestBody B b) {
         return getResponseEntityInformationWhatever(b);
    }
}
```

So the form kind of dynamically generates the "hidden" type fields and tries to submit the form to something like:

```
<form method="post" ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="n" value="3" />

    <input type="hidden" name="m['someKey']['a']" value="foo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="m['someKey']['b']" value="bar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="m['someKey']['c']" value="foobar" />

    <input type="hidden" name="m['anotherKey']['a']" value="one" />
    <input type="hidden" name="m['anotherKey']['b']" value="two" />
    <input type="hidden" name="m['anotherKey']['c']" value="three" />
</form>
```

*Note*: I also tried without `'` (ie. `m[someKEy][a]`)
*Note 2*: Every example here I typed manually on SO, the real example is a bit bigger, so please ignore syntax errors.

Is there any native way for spring to pick up this information, or do I have to do it another way?
Currently the requests returns with 415 and the controller doesn't even pick up the request.

Thanks

**EDIT**

When switching `@RequestBody B b` with `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params` I get appropriate map back. So in this context something like:

```
{
    "n": 3,
    "m['someKey']['a']": "foo",
    "m['someKey']['b']": "bar",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tired using `@RequestParam Map<String,String> params` ? . share the request body sent as part of the network request to debug further

Comment: @Barath No, I'll try and see where it leads me. Thanks!

Comment: @Barath edited description

Comment: try getting as map of request params and it should work. If you want to go with complex backing object. then you will have to populate those values accordingly.